# C++ division of variable and constant not working

Tags: c++, decimal, division

i've checked everywhere for answers and i can't figure out why if i enter stnumber as 123 it doesn't come out as 1.23, but 1, and if i enter 0.123 it also comes out as 1. i just started learning C++, so i may be making a obvious mistake i don't understand, and if so i apologize for doing so. This isn't part the main() function so return stnumber sends that back. Edit: I put the entire program here now.

```
#include <iostream>

int stsc()
{
    std::cout << "enter your number" << std::endl;
    long double stnumber = 1.0;
    std::cin >> stnumber;
    for (;;) {
        if (stnumber >= 1.0) {
            if (stnumber < 10.0) {
                return stnumber;
            }
            stnumber = stnumber / 10.0;
        }
        if (stnumber < 1.0) {
            stnumber = stnumber * 10.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're probably using an `int` somewhere. Can you give us a [mcve]?

Comment: The use of long double is unusual. While it might not relate to your problem, I would question that you need 16 byte/80 bit floating point precision.

Comment: the only 'int' is used to call this function from the 'main()' function, theres no 'int' in this function

Comment: @Avalanche can you show your `main`? The problem is probably there and not in this function.

Comment: The code you show is *not* a "function", it's just some lines that could be *part* of a function. We need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be able to properly help you. That of course include the complete function, and a `main` function which calls that function and displays the (wrong) result.

Comment: For the future, I'd recommend that you learn how to use a debugger. Would have probably at least isolated where the problem happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int stsc()
```

is the problem. Make that

```
long double stsc()
```

The function is returning an integer value and your variable stnumber is rounded down before it is printed.

Comment: i'll try it, i thought the function type didn't matter, thanks a lot. :) Edit : i compiled and ran it, it works now, can't thank you enough.

Comment: @Avalanche Why don't you think the return type would not matter? It's the type that the function actually returns, no matter the expression passed to the `return` statement.